# C# SQL Dependency only works for insert, not update on 1 server

Tags: c#, sql-server

So we have a sql dependency, and it only triggers onchange if it's a insert.  An update doesn't trigger it.

Now it works fine on 3 servers, but for only 1 server we see this behavior.  I can't think of any reason why update wouldn't work while insert does.  There's no code difference on the query, it's the same on all machines.

Any thoughts on how to debug this?

Comment: Can you share the code of the trigger, also the Update statement which does not make the trigger to execute.

Comment: Answered below, only was checking 1 column

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/455c1c94-3226-46e7-a898-d63d5d3310f0/sql-dependency-in-sql-server-2012?forum=sqldatabaseengine

"My (software) clients would set up QN using column A in above records. In SQL server 2008, notification would 'fire' every time column C was updated, even though column 'A' was being 'watched' by clients. Not so in SQL Server 2012."

Comment: So the answer is you have a bug in your procedure?

Comment: No, the answer is that 2008 sql server will check all the columns in the row to see if there are any changes.  In  > 2012 SQL server you have to specify which columns to check.  I'm guessing this would improve performance, that's why they did it.